# Multiple filters in a list

Tags: list-view, filter

I am using SharePoint online and want to add multiple filters on the list without coding. To enable the user to use different filters on the list. For example choosing created between two dates and/or choosing products from a dropdownlist etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter WebPart for multiple filters.When you want to filter between two dates then you need to use SP Designer to pass parameters.And for by default functionality SP only provide Choice filter WebPart not any specific to dropdown.

Find the screenshot below

[image]

I used to filters Choice filter and Text filter and applied both.The two filter are working perfectly fine.

Please let me know if i understood your requirement correctly.